# После добавление проекта вылетает ошибка 500

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте!
Помогите, пожалуйста, уже 3-й час сижу не могу найти ошибку. После добавление проекта в админке у меня браузер выдает ошибку 500

Вот код:

```
// Добавление нового проекта
if (isset($_POST['add_project_submit_rus'])) {
    // POST DATA
    $project_name_rus = defender_hack($_POST['project_name_rus']);
    $project_text_rus = defender_hack($_POST['project_text_rus']);
    $project_page_title_rus = defender_hack($_POST['project_page_title_rus']);
    $project_page_keywords_rus = defender_hack($_POST['project_page_keywords_rus']);
    $project_page_seo_description_rus = defender_hack($_POST['project_page_seo_description_rus']);
    $project_page_og_title_rus = defender_hack($_POST['project_page_og_title_rus']);
    $project_page_og_description_rus = defender_hack($_POST['project_page_og_description_rus']);

    // Настройки для изображений
    $project_index = 1;
    $project_post_id = $main_post_id + 1;
    $project_top = 0;
    $project_view = 0;
    // Настройки для изображений

    // PHOTO UPLOAD
    foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$f) {
        if (!$_FILES['file']['error'][$k]) {
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k])) {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $dir_slider . $_FILES['file']['name'][$k])) {
                }
            }
        }
        // for ($i=0; $i < $project_index; $i++) {}
        // Таблица изображений
        $fullfile = "https://site.org/uploads/project/".$_FILES['file']['name'][$k];
        $image = "insert into file_multi values(NULL, \"{$fullfile}\", \"{$project_index}\", \"{$project_top}\", \"{$project_post_id}\", \"{$project_name_rus}\")";
        if (mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")) {
            $conn->query($image);
        }
        // Таблица изображений
    }
    // Добавление информации о проектк
    $project_table = "insert into project_element values(NULL, \"{$project_name_rus}\", \"{$project_text_rus}\", \"{$project_page_title_rus}\", \"{$project_page_keywords_rus}\", \"{$project_page_seo_description_rus}\", \"{$project_page_og_title_rus}\", \"{$project_page_og_description_rus}\", \"{$project_view}\")";
    if (mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")) {
        $conn->query($project_table);
    }
    // Добавление информации о проектк
    echo "<script>alert('Добавлен новый товар');</script>";
}
// Добавление нового проекта
```

Comment: Вы не в браузер смотрите, а лог ошибок на сервере.

Comment: Может в коде дело? где то неправильное условие или перенапряг базы  данных?

Comment: Вы в лог ошибок на сервере посмотрели?

Comment: у меня есть 2 запроса, один добавляет информации о проекте в одну таблицу, а другой запрос добавляет изображения в таблицу изображений. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Смотрел, ничего не понятно.

Comment: Значит добавьте в вопрос текст ошибки, которая есть в логе ошибок сервера.

Comment: Это не ошибки и не из того файла. Вы в лог доступа смотрите. И удалите этот свой комментарий в целях безопасности ;)

Comment: просмотрите пожалуйста код, все ли там в порядке. Возможно причина кроется там

Comment: Довольно знакомый код :D Можете сделать try catch, возможно ошибка поймается. echo "<script>alert('Добавлен новый товар');</script>"; не делайте так ._. ваш браузер может посчитать это за спам назойливый и  не обработать скрипт. Создайте переменную типа <div id="success">text</div> и если скрипт отработал показать поле на время =0

Comment: $fullfile = "https://site.org/uploads/project/
так вообще никогда не делайте!!!! Храните пути и прочие параметры в конфиг-файле в защищенной папке .__.

Comment: этот код находится в файле, которая лежит в папке админки, к ней доступ из вне закрыт и стоит 2 уровня авторизации, вряд ли кому-то захочется тратить время ради этого.

Comment: Я говорю про возможное дальнейшее использование, если везде ставите в коде абсолютные пути, тогда например при смене домена, придётся копаться по всему коду...

Comment: а ну это да, тут я тупанул немного )