# PHP ошибка 500 после выполнения скрипта

Tags: php, sql

Ошибка 500 может возникнуть от нескольких запросов одновременно?

Comment: Ошибка 500 возникает из-за внутренней ошибки сервера, в частности причиной ошибки могут стать зависшие  или выполняющиеся процессы, вызванные большим количеством запросов на сервер. В зависимости от характеристик сервера для того, чтобы его положить может хватить и нескольких запросов.

Comment: Дубль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685970/php-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-500